# Kotlin class generics without duplication

Tags: kotlin

Consider an abstract class:

```
abstract class PubSubSubscriber<T : Any>(private val topic: KClass<T>) : BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
    abstract fun consume(payload: T)

    override fun accept(message: PubSubMessage, context: Context) {
        val json = String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.data.toByteArray()))
        val payload = objectMapper.readValue(json, topic.java)
        consume(payload)
    }
}
```

And implementation:

```
class MySubscriber : PubSubSubscriber<Payload>(Payload::class) {
```

Is there a way to define such abstract class so that I don't have to repeat twice the `Payload` and `Payload::class` in the class definition?

Comment: Not without extensive use of reflection. And in that case, repackage TypeToken from Guava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, with some reflection.

At construction time, we can extract the type parameter and assign it to a property that no longer needs to be given to the constructor:

```kotlin
abstract class PubSubSubscriber<T : Any> {

    val topic: KClass<T> = extractTypeParam<T>(0).kotlin

    private fun <X> extractTypeParam(paramIdx: Int): Class<X> {
        require(PubSubSubscriber::class.java == javaClass.superclass) {
            "PubSubSubscriber subclass $javaClass should directly extend PubSubSubscriber"
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[paramIdx] as Class<X>
    }

    abstract fun consume(payload: T)

    override fun accept(message: PubSubMessage, context: Context) {
        val json = String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.data.toByteArray()))
        val payload = objectMapper.readValue(json, topic.java)
        consume(payload)
    }
```

Note the following limitations:

A) this solution works only if `MySubscriber` directly extends from `PubSubSubscriber`. However, the given code can detect if that's *not* the case and warn about it (at runtime). In such cases, there are the following solutions:

1. `MySubscriber` falls back to providing a duplicate argument (essentially what you already had)
2. the direct superclass of `MySubscriber` can provide a similar detection mechanism

B) You call reflection code every time a `MySubscriber` instance is created. This may be too slow in certain contexts, but for many this is unproblematic.

Comment: I was sure there must be a way with Kotlin :-) Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this solution is applicable to Java, too. It has more to do with the JVM (and it's erasure) than a specific language. Anyway, glad you were helped.